# word2vec for propernouns

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, word2vec, word-embeddings

I have trained my word2vec model on a movie dataset with star cast, director name and other similar features/columns in the training data set. The text is not free flowing (it is comma separated). As a result, the SIMILARITY function and SCORE functions don’t produce satisfactory results as embedding generated are not up to the mark

1. Is word2vec the right approach for such a problem with more large number of proper nouns and no free flowing text?
2. If yes, which parameters to tune for training with proper nouns?

Comment: Make sure you have enough occurences of the proper nouns you are looking to learn the context for, if you have only one or two instances of such words in your corpus, there is no way your model will be able to learn any good semantic representation of the word.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of approaching improving that word2vec model.

Try removing all the commas, creating a continuous block of text to train word2vec.

There is also a concept called "fine tuning", it is a variation of transfer learning. Find a set of pre-trained word2vec weights and use those as the initial weights (word2vec weights are typically initialized as random). Then update the weights with your dataset. The pre-trained weights give the general patterns in words and better embed rare words. The fine tuning will improve the generic embeddings to model your particular dataset.

Lastly when tokenizing your dataset make sure you create the correct [collocations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation). For example, "Brad Pitt" should be "brad_pitt" (instead of "brad" and "pritt" separately). You can also recode all relevant mentions of "Brad" into "brad_pitt". Collocations carry much of the semantic meaning in proper nouns.